# Zombiejs - fetching contents of links synchronouly

Tags: node.js, zombie.js, node-async

I have been playing with nodejs and zombiejs to fetch some personal data from a site. Unfortunately I am stuck at a point where zombiejs only gets me the data from first link and then hangsup.

The steps I follow are-

1. Go to to the base url
2. Get the number of pages
3. Use async library to fetch them in series by opening a new browser window everytime. Note I only create a browser window instead of a totally new browser instance as it expensive to create one.

This is my code

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var async = require('async');

var so_base="http://stackoverflow.com";
var so_url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=newest&pagesize=15&page=";

var browser = new Browser();
browser.visit(so_base, function () {
    var arr=[];
    for(var i=1;i<=10;i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
    async.eachSeries(
                arr,
                function(k, callback) {
                        browser.open();
                        browser.visit(so_url+k,function() { 
                                console.log(browser.location.href);
                                console.log(browser.html());           
                        });
                },
                function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                });
});
```

Results

```
>node main_zombie.js 
..... HTML DUMP
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=newest&pagesize=15&page=1
>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake

As per https://github.com/caolan/async#each

One needs to call the callback function with empty arguments or null if there is no error.
So the correct code would be

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
var async = require('async');

var so_base="http://stackoverflow.com";
var so_url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java?sort=newest&pagesize=15&page=";

var browser = new Browser();
browser.visit(so_base, function () {
    var arr=[];
    for(var i=1;i<=10;i++) {
      arr.push(i);
    }
    async.eachSeries(
                arr,
                function(k, callback) {
                        browser.open();
                        browser.visit(so_url+k,function() { 
                                console.log(browser.location.href);
                                console.log(browser.html());
                        // Add callback and check if we reached the last page
                                if (k == 10) {
                                  browser.close();
                                }
                                callback();
                        });
                },
                function(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                });
});
```